# (android) Problems with random changes in dynamic nested recycler view items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image: 사지]

[image]

Hi,
I'm making a dynamic `Nested RecyclerView`.

The `Outer RecyclerView (Routine)` consists of parts (A, B, C...), add button,

and delete button, and the `inner RecyclerView (Detail Routine)` consists of text view (set, weight and count).

When i add an outer item, it have one inner `RecyclerView` item by default.

I thought the implementation was successful, but it wasn't.

The picture is a condition that I have made some items in advance.

This is a picture that creates additional items there.

However, in the picture, when I added the `G item`, you can see that the `F item`

and the `B item` have a change.

And the G item, oddly enough, has two basic items. Originally, it is one.

The second picture is the later item addition.

If i add a new `outer recyclerview` item, there will be a new change in the whole

item again.

I am not sure why this change is happening. If you add a new item, you want the

existing item to remain.

Please tell me the cause

Here is Code

***RoutineAdapter.java ( Outer RecyclerView Adpater )***

```
public class RoutineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoutineAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<RoutineModel> routineItems = new ArrayList<>();
    public RoutineDetailAdapter detailAdapter;
    OnRoutineItemClickListener listener;

    public void setOnRoutineClickListener(OnRoutineItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void addItem(RoutineModel item) {
        routineItems.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addDetailItem(RoutineDetailAdapter curDetailAdapter) {
        curDetailAdapter.addItem(new RoutineDetailModel());
    }
    public void deleteDetailItem(RoutineDetailAdapter curDetailAdapter) {
        curDetailAdapter.deleteItem();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.routine_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        detailAdapter = new RoutineDetailAdapter();
        holder.setRoutineDetailRecyClerView();
        holder.rv_detail.setAdapter(detailAdapter);
        detailAdapter.addItem(new RoutineDetailModel());

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RoutineModel curRoutineItem = routineItems.get(position);
        holder.setItems(curRoutineItem);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return routineItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        RecyclerView rv_detail;
        TextView routine;
        Button addSet;
        Button deleteSet;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            initViews();

            addSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    RoutineDetailAdapter curDetailAdapter = (RoutineDetailAdapter) rv_detail.getAdapter();
                    listener.OnAddBtnClick(curDetailAdapter);
                }
            });

            deleteSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    RoutineDetailAdapter curDetailAdapter = (RoutineDetailAdapter) rv_detail.getAdapter();
                    listener.OnDeleteBtnClick(curDetailAdapter);
                }
            });
        }

        private void initViews() {
            routine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.routine);
            rv_detail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail_routine);
            addSet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_set);
            deleteSet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_set);
        }
        private void setItems(RoutineModel routineItem) {
            routine.setText(routineItem.getRoutine());
        }

        public void setRoutineDetailRecyClerView() {
            rv_detail.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        }
    }

    public interface OnRoutineItemClickListener {
        public void OnAddBtnClick(RoutineDetailAdapter detailAdapter);
        public void OnDeleteBtnClick(RoutineDetailAdapter detailAdapter);
    }
}
```

***RoutineDetailAdapter.java ( Inner RecyclerView Adapter )***

```
public class RoutineDetailAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RoutineDetailAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    int insertPosition;
    int deletePosition;

    public void addItem(RoutineDetailModel item) {
        items.add(item);
        notifyItemInserted(insertPosition);
    }

    public void deleteItem() {
        try {
            if(items.size() > 1) { // Leave at least one set
                items.remove(deletePosition);
                notifyItemRemoved(deletePosition);
                deletePosition -= 1;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // empty
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> getItem() {
        return this.items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.routine_detail_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RoutineDetailModel item = items.get(position);
        holder.setItem(item, position);
        insertPosition = position + 1;
        deletePosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView set;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            set = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set);
        }

        private void setItem(RoutineDetailModel item, int setCount) {
            set.setText(setCount + 1 + "set");
        }
    }
}
```

***WriteRoutineActivity.java***

```
public class WriteRoutineActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button add_routine_btn;
    TextView title;
    RecyclerView routine_rv;

    RoutineAdapter routineAdapter;
    LinearLayoutManager routineLayoutManger;
    ArrayList<String> titleData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_write_routine);

        initViews();
        setPageTitle(getIntent());
        setRoutineRecyclerview();

        routineAdapter = new RoutineAdapter();
        routine_rv.setAdapter(routineAdapter);

        add_routine_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WorkoutListDialogFragment routineDialog = new WorkoutListDialogFragment();
                routineDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "RoutineListDialog");
            }
        });

        routineAdapter.setOnRoutineClickListener(new RoutineAdapter.OnRoutineItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnAddBtnClick(RoutineDetailAdapter curDetailAdapter) {
                routineAdapter.addDetailItem(curDetailAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void OnDeleteBtnClick(RoutineDetailAdapter curDetailAdapter) {
                routineAdapter.deleteDetailItem(curDetailAdapter);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initViews() {
        title = findViewById(R.id.body_part_detail_title);
        routine_rv = findViewById(R.id.routine_recyclerview);
        add_routine_btn = findViewById(R.id.add_routine);
    }

    private void setRoutineRecyclerview() {
        routineLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        routine_rv.setLayoutManager(routineLayoutManger);
        routine_rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration divider = new DividerItemDecorator(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.divider));
        routine_rv.addItemDecoration(divider);
    }

    public void setPageTitle(Intent intent) {
        if(intent != null) {
            titleData = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("bodypart");
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                String new_title = String.join(" / ", titleData);
                title.setText(new_title);
            }
            else {
                StringBuilder new_title = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < titleData.size(); i++) {
                    if (i == titleData.size() - 1) {
                        new_title.append(titleData.get(i));
                        break;
                    }
                    new_title.append(titleData.get(i)).append(" / ");
                }
                title.setText(new_title);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addRoutine(String routine) {
        routineAdapter.addItem(new RoutineModel(routine));
        routine_rv.smoothScrollToPosition(routineAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
    }
}
```

***ADDED***

***Main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".data.DailyRecordDetailActivity">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/body_part_detail_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="PART"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_routine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ROUTINE ADD"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/light_green"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/routine_recyclerview"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/routine_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_routine"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

***RoutineItem.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_routine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/routine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="ROUTINE"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_set"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="ADD"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_set"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="DELETE"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/detail_routine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear_routine"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***RoutineDetail.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/set"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="SET"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0 kg"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every RoutineModel item you recreate detailAdapter but you need new instance. Check TODO in code below:

```
public class RoutineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoutineAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        Context context;
        ArrayList<RoutineModel> routineItems = new ArrayList<>();
        //public RoutineDetailAdapter detailAdapter; //TODO move it to local variable in method onCreateViewHolder
        OnRoutineItemClickListener listener;
```

like this

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.routine_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        RoutineDetailAdapter detailAdapter = new RoutineDetailAdapter(); //TODO Create local variable
        detailAdapter.addItem(new RoutineDetailModel());
        holder.setRoutineDetailRecyClerView();
        holder.rv_detail.setAdapter(detailAdapter);

        return holder;
    }
```

**But this is not good way to solve this... Its better to use one Adapter with multiple item views. I have no time now to explain, I will post some code later...**

**EDITED**

I had same problem and and solved this on this (better) way:

Create Adapter that support multiple views

```
public class MultipleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Object> items; //List<Object or Generic class or abstarct base Model class parent of Routine and RoutineDetails>
    private OnItemClickListener listener; //TODO new interface

        ..............

}
```

Override onCreateViewHolder like this

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == 1){
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.routine_item, parent, false);
            return new RoutineViewHolder (itemView);
        }/*else{*/
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.routine_detail_item, parent, false);
            return new RoutineDetailsViewHolder (itemView);
        //}
    }
```

Override onBindViewHolder like this and create your updateViews methods

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Object object = items.get(position); //Object or Generic class or abstarct base Model class parent of Routine and RoutineDetails>
    if(object instanceof RoutineModel) {
        //create method
        updateRoutineViews((RoutineViewHolder) holder, (RoutineModel) object, position);
    }else if(object instanceof RoutineDetailsModel) {
        //create method
        updateRoutineDetailsViewHolder((RoutineDetailsViewHolder) holder, (RoutineDetailModel) object);
    }
}
```

and override getItemViewType method

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Object object = items.get(position);
        if(object instanceof RoutineModel){
            return 1;
        }
        //else if instanceOf RoutineDetailModel return 0
        return 0; 
    }
```

This is so simple and better for performance...

Also in OnItemClickListener get item by position and check instanceOf object like above. You can add new item to the clickedItemPosition + 1 with adapter.notifyDataSetChanges()

In MainActivity you have to create mixed list with Routine and Routine details

```
List<Object> mixedList = new ArrayList<>();
for(RoutineModel rm: routineList){
    mixedList.add(rm);
    if(rm has routineDetailModels){ //pseudo code
        for(RoutineDetailModels rmdetilas: rm.getRoutineDetailModels()){
            mixedList.add(rmdetilas);
        }
    }
}
adpater.swapData(mixedList); //create your method to swap or set data to adapter
```

EDITED
handle click

```
public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onClick(View view, int position);
    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}
```

and

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Object item = (Object) adapter.getItem(position);
            if(item instanceof Routine) {
                if (view.getId() == R.id.delete_id) {
                    //TODO delete form list, notifyItemRemoved or generate all mixeddata again and swap
                } else if (view.getId() == R.id.whateveryouwant) {
                    //TODO doSomething()
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    });
```

The code above is just an example of how to solve the problem
For more help feel free to comment

**EDITED 2**

```
public class RoutineViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    public RecyclerView rv_detail;
    public TextView routine;
    public Button addSet;
    public Button deleteSet;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //initViews(); in constructor
        routine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.routine);
        rv_detail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail_routine);
        addSet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_set);
        deleteSet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_set);
    } 
}
```

update method called from onBindViewHolder

```
private void updateRoutineViews(RoutineViewHolder holder, RoutineModel routineItem, position){
    holder.routine.setText(routineItem.getRoutine());
    holder.rv_detail.setText(routineItem.getWhateverYouWant());

    holder.deleteSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onItemClickListener.onClick(v, position); //or holder.getAdapterPosition()
        }
    });
}
```

---

**COMPLETE CODE**

Create complete new app to test it and understand (copy/paste this code), then integrate in your app...

There are more improvements but I don't have time, this is a quick fix

Activity

```
public class RoutineActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MultipleViewAdapter adapter;
    private List<RoutineModel> routineList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_routine);

        RecyclerView contentList = findViewById(R.id.list);
        contentList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new MultipleViewAdapter(this, new ArrayList<>());
        contentList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MultipleViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Object item = (Object) adapter.getItem(position);
                if(item instanceof RoutineModel) {
                    RoutineModel routineModel = (RoutineModel) item;
                    if (view.getId() == R.id.add_set) {
                        int weight = randomInt(99);
                        Toast.makeText(RoutineActivity.this, "New item with weight: " + weight + " kg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        routineModel.addDetails(new RoutineDetailsModel(routineModel.getDetailsSize() + 1, weight));
                        adapter.swapData(getMixedList()); // OR add item to adapter and notify item inserted
                        //TODO implement SnappingLinearLayoutManager and set list.smoothScroleto... routineModel
                    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.delete_set) {
                        //TODO doSomething()
                        boolean deleted = routineModel.removeDetails(routineModel.getDetailsSize() - 1); // -1 !!! to delete last item
                        Toast.makeText(RoutineActivity.this, deleted ? "Last item is deleted": "No more items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        adapter.swapData(getMixedList()); // OR remove item from adapter and notify item removed
                        //TODO implement SnappingLinearLayoutManager and set list.smoothScroleto.... routineModel
                    }

                }else if(item instanceof RoutineDetailsModel) {
                    RoutineDetailsModel routineModel = (RoutineDetailsModel) item;
                    Toast.makeText(RoutineActivity.this, "Weight: " + routineModel.getWeight() + " kg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //TODO EDITED 4 (copy/paste this) random new Weight
                routineModel.setWeight(randomInt(99));
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
                Toast.makeText(RoutineActivity.this, "New Weight: " + routineModel.getWeight() + " kg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        });

        initFakeData();
        adapter.swapData(getMixedList());
    }


    private List<Object> getMixedList() {
        List<Object> mixedList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(RoutineModel rm: routineList){
            mixedList.add(rm);
            if(rm.getRoutineDetailsModel() != null && rm.getRoutineDetailsModel().size() > 0){
                for(RoutineDetailsModel rmdetilas: rm.getRoutineDetailsModel()){
                    mixedList.add(rmdetilas);
                }
            }
        }
        return mixedList;
    }


    private void initFakeData() {
        routineList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            RoutineModel routineModel = new RoutineModel(String.valueOf(i + 1));
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                routineModel.addDetails(new RoutineDetailsModel(j+1, randomInt(99)));
            }
            routineList.add(routineModel);
        }
    }

    private int randomInt(int max) {
        return (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    }
}
```

Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter

```
public class MultipleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context context; // TODO only if you need conetxt
    private List<Object> items;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public MultipleViewAdapter(Context context, List<Object> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == 1){
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.routine_item, parent, false);
            return new RoutineViewHolder(itemView);
        }/*else{*/
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.routine_detail_item, parent, false);
        return new RoutineDetailsViewHolder(itemView);
        //}
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Object object = items.get(position); //Object or Generic class or abstarct base Model class parent of Routine and RoutineDetails>
        if(object instanceof RoutineModel) {
            updateRoutineViews((RoutineViewHolder) holder, (RoutineModel) object, position);
        }else if(object instanceof RoutineDetailsModel) {
            updateRoutineDetailsViewHolder((RoutineDetailsViewHolder) holder, (RoutineDetailsModel) object, position);
        }
    }

    private void updateRoutineViews(RoutineViewHolder holder, RoutineModel routineItem, int position){
        holder.routine.setText("Routine " + routineItem.getRoutine());

        holder.addSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(onItemClickListener != null) onItemClickListener.onClick(v, position);
            }
        });

        holder.deleteSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(onItemClickListener != null) onItemClickListener.onClick(v, position);
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateRoutineDetailsViewHolder(RoutineDetailsViewHolder holder, RoutineDetailsModel routineDetailsModel, int position){
        holder.set.setText(routineDetailsModel.getSet() + " set");
        holder.weight.setText(routineDetailsModel.getWeight()  + " kg");
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(onItemClickListener != null) onItemClickListener.onClick(v, position);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Object object = items.get(position);
        if(object instanceof RoutineModel){
            return 1;
        }
        //else if instanceOf RoutineDetailModel return 0
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(items == null) return 0;
        return items.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if(this.items == null || position < 0 || position >= this.items.size()) return null;
        return this.items.get(position);
    }

    public void swapData(List<Object> newItems) {
        if (newItems != null) {
            this.items = newItems;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onClick(View view, int position);
        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }


    public static class RoutineViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        public TextView routine;
        public Button addSet;
        public Button deleteSet;

        public RoutineViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //initViews(); in constructor
            routine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.routine);
            addSet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_set);
            deleteSet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_set);
        }
    }

    public static class RoutineDetailsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView set;
        public TextView weight;
        public RoutineDetailsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            set = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set);
            weight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.weight);
        }
    }



}
```

RoutineModel

```
public class RoutineModel {

    private List<RoutineDetailsModel> routineDetailsList;
    private String routine;

    public RoutineModel(String routine) {
        this.routine = routine;
    }

    public List<RoutineDetailsModel> getRoutineDetailsModel() {
        return routineDetailsList;
    }

    public void setRoutineDetailsModel(List<RoutineDetailsModel> routineDetailsModel) {
        this.routineDetailsList = routineDetailsModel;
    }

    public void addDetails(RoutineDetailsModel item) {
        if(routineDetailsList == null) {
            routineDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.routineDetailsList.add(item);
    }
    public boolean removeDetails(int index) {
        if(routineDetailsList == null || index >= routineDetailsList.size() || index < 0) return false;
        this.routineDetailsList.remove(index);
        return true;
    }

    public String getRoutine() {
        return routine;
    }

    public void setRoutine(String routine) {
        this.routine = routine;
    }

    public int getDetailsSize() {
        if(routineDetailsList == null) return 0;
        return routineDetailsList.size();
    }
}
```

RoutineDetailsModel

```
public class RoutineDetailsModel {

    private int set;
    private int weight;

    public RoutineDetailsModel(int set, int weight) {
        this.set = set;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getSet() {
        return set;
    }

    public void setSet(int set) {
        this.set = set;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Item layouts

Find in question: **routine_item.xml** and **routine_detail_item.xml**

Comment: I just created a new project and ran your code.
The result works fine.
And now I'm reading line by line to understand your code.
After understanding, I will apply it to my code.
I'm really grateful and I'm sorry to have been frustrated for days.

Comment: It was slow, but I understood almost all of your code... but I'll ask you one more question. This is a question about Java's syntax. You assigned the values ​​you put in the variable `routineList (RoutineModel)` to the variable `mixedList` in `getMixedList()`.
However, `getMixedList()` is called even when `routineModel` is added or deleted in the add/delete click event. Is the change of `routineList` value (Size,RoutineModel) because of Java's `call by Reference`? The sentence may be strange because I am not good at English. Please understand. :)

Comment: I added some new code. Ctrl+F = EDITED 4, copy/paste new code in new app and check (click on details item mode)

Comment: I'll ask you one question. In the `MainActivity's initFakeData()`, you use a `List<Object>` to store both the `RoutineList class` and the `RoutineDetail class`. After saving in `mixedList` in `getMixedList() method`, `mixedList` has 25 sizes. There are two indexes, RoutineList and RoutineDetail
However, when the index is `RoutineList` in `mixedList`, this also has RoutineDetailList inside. This is redundant. So I want to save only `RoutineList` and display it to adapter, but I don't know how to display RoutineDetail inside RoutineList. `notifySetDataChanged()` does not work on `DetailList`.

Comment: Sorry I just see your last comment. My goal was to show you how to solve RecyclerView with multiple viewHolders, how to use parameter viewType and @Override method getItemViewType(). Fake data is only there to make a mixed list and I haven't even thought about it too much because I really don't know the Source of the data and how do you Get them... The list works perfectly and smoothly (I tested this on real device) . And without nested lists that are always complicated for ux. The expandable list works in a similar way. Also RoutineDetail is one object per reference for both lists...