# (android) Should setAdapter() be called only the first time?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

This is not code Question.

As I saw on some website, RecyclerView's setAdapter should be run only once the first time.

What is the reason?

If so, in the Nested RecyclerView, the person of this video keeps calling the

setAdapter() of the Sub  RecyclerView every time it is recycled in

onBindViewHolder(), is it wrong??

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyUjw6b5gXE

***ADDED***
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No he is right I think. Let see the logic which was proposed in the video. You have `parent` list with `child` items. It is ordinary situation as I know. But every `child` item in `parent` list is `parent` item for its list which is stored inside the `child` item of the `parent` list. So when you call `setAdapter()` inside container of `parent` list you send data to its `children`  and their `children` And what about `onBindViewHolder()`, why `setAdapter` is called every time? It is very simple, let see into [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview):

> RecyclerView calls this method to associate a ViewHolder with data.
> The method fetches the appropriate data and uses the data to fill in
> the view holder's layout. For example, if the RecyclerView displays a
> list of names, the method might find the appropriate name in the list
> and fill in the view holder's TextView widget.

So when you send data for the first level RV you associate child RV with some data for which purpose you call `setAdapter` in each item of `parent` list. So it will be called in every position of the `parent` list item to assign data to the `child` list which also will have some data holders with its handling. Let see life example:

```
grandfather (activity) bought some candies for his children (first level list items) who will give some of them to their children (second level lists which are items of first level list items)
```

and for passing some candies between among relatives we use `setAdapter()` method :) I hope I explained your question and you will understand this video :D

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I can't understand the video because I'm not good at English. Sorry. :(

So I read your answer and try to understand it, but there are some sentences that are a bit difficult to understand.

`But every child item in parent list is parent item for its list which is stored inside the child item of the parent list`  -> i can't understand this part well.

Comment: hmm... let see from another side, you have your parents and you have your children, you are like `parent` list item which has its own parent = list and which has its own child = list :)

Comment: To be honest, I haven't fully understood that sentence yet.. But I added your answer by drawing a picture. Can you see it?

Is what you are trying to say?..

Are you saying that `setAdapter()` is called when adding an `inner RV item` to each outer RV item?


Does that mean it doesn't matter if `setAdapter()` is called multiple times?

Comment: Yes, you are right) It is graphical representation of my answer)))

Comment: I didn't fully understand your sentence, but I'm glad I did.
Then I'm sorry, but I'll ask you a few more questions.

1. You said that each parent item in a `nested recyclerview` calls `setAdapter()` for each subitem. Shouldn't this be called in `onCreateViewHolder()`? Does it cause problems when recycling subitems? In fact, when I called `setAdapter()` of a subitem in `onCreateViewHolder()`, there was a problem that the item changes randomly when adding the parent item.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65863588/android-problems-with-random-changes-in-dynamic-nested-recycler-view-items

Comment: 2. In the nested recycler view, I called setAdapter() every time on a subitem. By the way, in the normal recycler view, not the nested recycler view, setAdapter() is called only once in onCreate() rather than for each item. How is this possible?

Is this not actually called only once, but is added every time an item is added?

Comment: 1. no, it has to be called inside `onBindViweHolder` because here data will be assigned to the current position view and data also will be sent to the child RV

2. you call one time inside onCreate() because your first container is activity and in second time it will be RV item which is not an activity :)

Comment: second answer - Does the word `second time` mean that setAdapter() is called multiple times? Sorry. I didn't understand exactly.

Comment: If you have been given an exhaustive answer, mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark to the left of it.

Comment: Thanks. But in a `single recycler view`, isn't `setAdadpter()` called from `onCreate()` only called once the first time?
I just created a method and in it created a `Toast Message` to announce the call with `setAdapter()`.
However, `setAdapter()` was executed only once the first time, and the `Toast message` was not displayed in the data added afterwards. I mean in `Single RecyclerView`

Comment: You can for example call setAdapter for adapter refreshing, but in general yes, it is called one time

Comment: Thank you. Thank you so much for your kind response for a long time.